# Relation between mass, speed and acceleration in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, mass, speed-of-light

I heard it explained that Special Relativity does not actually forbid faster-than-light travel. Instead – it was argued – it is impossible to transcend the speed of light by any massive object, because, according to Special Relativity, mass increases with speed and becomes infinite at $c$, which means a body would take an infinite amount of energy to accelerate further. However, relativistic effects only apply to external observers moving relative to the observed object.

Being in a spaceship, stationary with respect to that ship, but observing its motion relative to a star, I perceive the mass of my ship as being constant (right?). How then can I explain the fact that it's increasingly difficult to accelerate the ship further as it travels faster and faster relative to the star? Can I use Special Relativity to predict increase in energy cost of further acceleration over increase of my speed relative to the star?

Comment: Relativistic mass is an outdated and confusing concept. It is the energy that depends on the referential, not the mass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can from the equation $E=\gamma mc^2$. You will find :
\begin{equation}
\frac{v^2}{c^2}=1-\frac{m^2 c^4}{E^2}
\end{equation}
Thus for the first term to be 1 you have to have an infinite amount of energy.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think that's what I was looking for. So if I understand correctly, I have to compute $E$ for my current and desired speed, and the difference of these is the energy I need to put into the spaceship in order to accelerate it to the desired speed, right?

Comment: I think this is correct.